# What is the meaning of the differential of a variable when the variable is the value of a constant function?

Tags: integration, notation

Sometimes you see integrals like

$$
\int_1^2 1 df(t)
$$

where the differential takes form "$df(t)$".  But is there any difference between this and

$$
\int_1^2 1 dx
$$

?

I ask because it's easy to imagine a case where $f(t) = 1$ for all $t$.  Then the term $df(t)$ (interpreted as an infinitesimal quantity) is always $0$ (since small changes in $f(t)$ are impossible).

**EDIT:** The context that this is taken from is a book called *No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics*:

> [image]

The statement $\int \frac{dx(t)}{x(t)} = \ln(x(t))$ in particular made think $dx(t)$ was just a synonym for $dx$ since $\int \frac{dx}{x} = \ln(x)$.

Comment: Yes, it is different. By definition, $df(t)$ means $f'(t) dt$. So your first integral is equal to $f(2) - f(1)$ by the fundamental theorem.

Comment: When you see $\int_a^b\dots\,\mathrm{d}F(t)$, the limits $a,b$ are really $t=a,b$, not $F(t)=a,b$.

Comment: This could refer to [Riemann-Stieljes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral?wprov=sfti1) integral.

Comment: @Nick [Not every derivative is Riemann integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function). And if the derivative is Riemann integrable but not defined everywhere and the original function isn't absolutely continuous, like for the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), then $f(2)-f(1)$ will give the wrong answer.

Comment: Where are you seeing this notation? Can you add context to your question? The exact meaning might depend slightly on that. If it's in a calculus class, Nick's comment may be enough. If it's in some other context, maybe you need what mathcounterexamples.net was saying.

Comment: @MarkS I added the context that I'm taking this from above.